# MySQL LEFT JOIN with one column in ON clause

Tags: mysql

Having a query that needs to be optimized, the query looks like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.column_1 = TableB.column_1
  AND TableB.column_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND TableB.column_3 IS NULL
  AND TableB.column_4 IS NULL
  AND TableB.column_5 IS NULL
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.column_1 = TableC.column_1
  AND TableC.column_3 IS NULL
  AND TableC.column_4 IS NULL
  AND TableC.column_5 IS NULL
```

The slow part in a query is a lot of `IS NULL` in `ON` clause. The time execution is around 4+ seconds. After playing with the query for a while i've noticed that `IS NULL` can be omitted from the fields in `ON` clause. Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.column_1 = TableB.column_1
  AND TableB.column_2 IS NOT NULL
  AND TableB.column_3
  AND TableB.column_4
  AND TableB.column_5
LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableA.column_1 = TableC.column_1
  AND TableC.column_3
  AND TableC.column_4
  AND TableC.column_5
```

The time execution for this query is **`53ms`**!, and the set of records is also the same as we have from the first query. Tried to google it and didn't find anything.

Does anyone know how it works?

MySQL version is `5.7.25`

***UPDATE***

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    `column_1` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `column_2` datetime  NULL,
    `column_3` datetime  NULL,
    `column_4` datetime  NULL,
    `column_5` datetime  NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE TableB (
    `column_1` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `column_2` datetime  NULL,
    `column_3` datetime  NULL,
    `column_4` datetime  NULL,
    `column_5` datetime  NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE TableC (
    `column_1` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `column_2` datetime  NULL,
    `column_3` datetime  NULL,
    `column_4` datetime  NULL,
    `column_5` datetime  NULL,
)

INSERT INTO `TableA` (`column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`, `column_4`, `column_5`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-08-13 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Didn't include indexes, but each field which is used in `ON` clause has index

Comment: Please include some sample data.  I suspect the reason is an artifact.

Comment: Well, everything can be omitted except lines 1,2,3, and 8, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen working on it.

Comment: Please include the indexes all three tables have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i just updated the question with the sample of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the table:

```
create table tablename (id int, col datetime);
insert into tablename (id, col) values
(5,   null),
(6,   '2019-01-06 11:38:41'),
(7,   '2019-01-06 11:39:40'),
(8,   '2019-01-06 11:39:49');
```

The query:

```
select * 
from tablename
where col
```

returns:

```
| id  | col                 |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 6   | 2019-01-06 11:38:41 |
| 7   | 2019-01-06 11:39:40 |
| 8   | 2019-01-06 11:39:49 |
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/7).
Meaning that in order to evaluate `col` as a value of `0` (False) or `1` (True), since the evaluation takes place in the `WHERE` clause, MySql converts any `non null` datetime value to a positive number `>0`, evaluating to True and any `null` value will evaluate to not True (so treated like False) .
What you describe is the exact opposite.
Because `TableB.column_3 IS NULL` and just `TableB.column_3` when evaluated as `>0` or `0` in a `WHERE` or `ON` clause return the opposite results.

Comment: This what i was expecting to get, i wasn't sure if the evaluating works in this way, do you have any links for this?

Comment: For what I describe in the answer no, I don't have anything from the documentation. There is this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html which describes "Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation" but not specifically for this case. My answer is based on what I've experienced happening in Mysql by playing with statements and data types. I hope that you read the last part of my answer where I say that what you describe is the exact opposite of what really happens.